# Inverse Fourier Transform of $\sqrt {-iw} \mathcal F(w)$

Tags: fourier-transform

If I use the following set of Fourier transforms:

$$\mathcal F(w) = \int_{0}^T dtf(t)e^{iwt},$$

$$ f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-w_N}^{w_N} dw\mathcal F(w)e^{-iwt},$$

where $f(t)$ is an arbitrary time domain signal with total duration $T$, $w= 2\pi f$ is angular frequency, and $w_N$ is the Nyquist angular frequency. The underlying assumption here is that the signal $f(t)$ is casual in the sense that it has a zero value for $t \leq 0$.

Now, what is the inverse Fourier Transform of $\sqrt {-iw} \mathcal F(w)$:

${}$
$$\mathcal F^{-1} (\sqrt {-iw} \mathcal F(w))=\quad?$$

${}$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Why are you interested in this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Refer [Table of Fourier/Inverse Fourier transform](https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ibk/structural-mechanics-dam/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf). And make it a good habit to write the differential after the integrand.

Comment: Fixed the link. It would be better if you included the relevant portions of the table here.

Comment: Could you please tell me which one can help me?